# Fadein in slider doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why is it omitting the last slide? How can I fix it to show the first image just after the side loads, without waiting? I've tried everything and cant fix it out, always were some problems (displaying two images at the same time etc) and now this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/19445204e2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Startowy slajd
        var numer = 0;
 
        function changeslide()
        {
            var imagesnumber=document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("img");

            for(var i = 0; i < imagesnumber.length; i++)
            {
                imagesnumber[i].style.display = "none";
            }
                
            // Wyswietlam aktualny index                
            $("#slide"+numer).fadeIn(500).css('display','block');

            if(numer >= imagesnumber.length-1)
                numer = 0;
            else
                numer++;
            
            timer1 = setTimeout("changeslide()", 3000);
        }
        </script>
        
    </head>
    <body onload="changeslide()">
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="slides/img1.jpg" id="slide1">
            <img src="slides/img2.jpg" id="slide2">
            <img src="slides/img3.jpg" id="slide3">
            <img src="slides/img4.jpg" id="slide4">
            <img src="slides/img5.jpg" id="slide5">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you place all your code in a working jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qkjrxos5/

I hope i've uploaded it right, never used that before

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeslide() {
  if (typeof this.numer === "undefined") this.numer = 1;
  var imagesnumber = document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("img");

  $("#slider img").css("display", "none");
  $("#slide" + numer).fadeIn(500).css('display', 'block');

  if (this.numer >= imagesnumber.length)
    this.numer = 1;
  else
    this.numer++;

  timer1 = setTimeout(changeslide, 3000);
}
```

I moved the counter to the function so you don't mess up your variables outside.

The counter restarted too early and I replaced your for loop with a jquery solution.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me what can I do with second problem? ( showing the first img right after the page is loaded without delay)

Comment: Take a look again

Comment: Thank you :) Could you tell me what this line:

  if (!this.numer) this.numer = 1;

 do?

@aleskv

Comment: A function is like an object. When you assign `this.anything` inside of a function it's like doing this with any other JS object. Because there is no `this.numer` the if-condition will fail and 'this.numer = 1` will be assigned. The second time this functiion is called, the condition doesn't apply because this.numer has a value > 0.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I updated the answer again. I hope it's clearer now with the this.numer thing. Now it's cleaner I think.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numer = 0;

function changeslide(){
            var timeout=0;
            if(numer!==0){
              timeout=3000;
            }
            var imagesnumber=document.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("img");



            for(var i = 0; i < imagesnumber.length; i++)
                {
                    imagesnumber[i].style.display = "none";
                }

            // Wyświetlam aktualny index

            $("#slide"+numer).fadeIn(500).css('display','block');


            if(numer >= imagesnumber.length-1)
                numer = 0;

            else
                numer++;



            timer1 = setTimeout("changeslide()", timeout);


        }
```

[PEN](http://codepen.io/kilotonna/pen/PWyyXg)